# Cytoscape cyPosition() vs zoom fit

Tags: cytoscape.js

Using Cytoscape.js v2.1, I noticed something that maybe a bug (from this version or maybe mine =p).

When inserting a node, I'm using this to get node position from the `tap` event `e`:

```
position = {
    x: e.cyPosition.x,
    y: e.cyPosition.y
};
```

Also, my cytoscape initializer is setting `layout fit`as `true`:

```
$cy.cytoscape({
    minZoom: 0.1,
    maxZoom: 2.0,
    layout: {
        fit: true
    }, 
(...)
```

And so the problems begin. Using this, on Windows 7, Chrome version 32.0.1700.107 or Firefox 27.0.1, the node is being positioned with a big offset (as shown [here](https://sandhi-syrtic.codio.io/index_fit.html)).

On the other hand, when I set `layout fit` as `false`, the node is correctly positioned. (as you can see in [this link](https://sandhi-syrtic.codio.io/)).

As it's happening only when initial zoom fit is `true`, I supose this is a specific bug of this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation regarding rendered versus model position.  I think you've confused the two: http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#notation/position

Model position must stay constant despite pan and zoom.  Otherwise, positions would be inconsistent.

On the other hand, rendered position is derived from the model position, pan, and zoom.  Naturally, model position and rendered position differ when zoom differs from identity (1) or pan differs from the origin (0, 0).

It doesn't look like you're using rendered position for on-screen placement.

Edit:

Don't mix and match rendered position with model position.  If you get model position in your handler (`e.cyPosition`), then continue to use model position to add nodes et cetera.  If you get rendered position (`e.cyRenderedPosition`), then use rendered position to add nodes et cetera.

Mixing the two will never give desired behaviour unless you do some math to translate them.